# Does Bluestacks support Renderscript?

Tags: renderscript

As the most of you will know Android Emulators for >3.x don't support Renderscript. Now I found an Android Player called Bluestacks (tge most of you will know it I think). So I wanted to ask, if it's just me or does Bluestacks also not support Renderscript.

Regards,
Ahmad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has published a compatibility library for Renderscript, which allows you to use it starting from Android 2.2 (API8).

This means that Renderscript could run even on bluestacks if it is still android 2.3.

The disadvantage is that it uses the CPU unless the OS version is 4.3 and above.

more information about it is available on the android developers blog, [**here**](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to support RenderScript. As RenderScript is a part of android framework, all renderscript openGLES operations should be forwarded to host stack eventually.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Bluestacks help forum](https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/what_version_of_android_is_bluestack_equivalent_to) Bluestacks is equivalent to Android 2.3.4 which doesn't support Renderscript as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the emulator images for Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.x) and JellyBean (4.1.x) which come with the Android SDK does support Renderscript. The Honeycomb (3.0, 3.1, 3.2) emulator images do not.